# Spring event to be fired on new year day

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using the latest version of Spring. I need to perform some DB operations when the year changes on new year day. Is there any way to fire up a Spring-based event to detect that year was changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in the comments this can be achieved by using the [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--) annotation.
The scheduled annotation allows us to define a cron expression that will deterimne when a method annoated with this annotation is going to be called. From the docs:

> **cron**
>
> A cron-like expression, extending the usual UN*X definition to
> include triggers on the second as well as minute, hour, day of month,
> month and day of week.

So for example, the method

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 1 *")
public void doStuffOnFirstOfJanuary() {
    System.err.println("This is called");
 }
```

Will be called on on every first day of January at 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds.

In order for this annotation to work you have to enable scheduling in your application, either by using the `@EnableScheduling` annotation or by adding the `<task:annotation-driven/>` element if you use xml configuration.